# Email Template processing Error

Tags: magento-1.9, template

I am getting an error in the email that is received. The email has an error at the top and the bottom and it also appears the css isn't styling the template.

Located at the top of the email:

**{Error in template processing} {{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}**
Located at the bottom of the email:

**{Error in template processing}**

I just cannot seem to find the root of this issue. I am new to magento and need a little assistance. I am using 1.9.0.1 Magento

Answer (score 0):

`email-inline.css` must be placed in your theme skin folder.

Copy this files `skin/frontend/base/default/css` to `skin/frontend/default/YOUR-THEME/css`

Comment: its not working..... error is not gone!!